# Processing error: unrecognized option `--request'

Tags: java, processing

i got this `java_home: unrecognized option '--request'`error when i try to run the standard examples. Some are still working but those in video/capture are not.

I think that it is got to do with Java? Iam on a mac.

[image: error]

FIXED: downgraded from processing 2.0 to 1.5

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: What standard examples are you talking about?

Comment: when you go to file and then examples. Then in the map libaries/video/capture. All those examples are not working

Comment: Should it be "-request" (one dash) and not "--request" (two dashes)?

Comment: no, i just updated my post with a image of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: downgraded from processing 2.0 to 1.5

Comment: it's just a warning, not an error.  it doesn't impact your program.  much better to stick with 2.0, so you don't have to upgrade later and deal with refactoring your code (a LOT of changes between 1.5 and 2.0).  `--request` seems to be a command-line argument, tho skimming PApplet.java i don't see it anywhere in the code.  could be that in the latest 2.0 beta the IDE is sending that command-line arg.